# Strange behaviour in installation of PHPUnit

Tags: installation, php, ubuntu-14.04, phpunit

I was trying to install PHPUnit following the step-by-step guide in the [Getting Started page](https://phpunit.de/getting-started.html).

However, when I try `phpunit --version` in terminal, I receive `/usr/local/bin/phpunit: Permission denied`.

Trying `sudo phpunit --version` the error is `sudo: phpunit: command not found`.

I already tried execute:

```
$ cd /usr/local/bin
$ ./phpunit --version
```

The error is `bash: ./phpunit: Permission denied` and with `sudo` I get `command not found` again.

Finally, using php before the command like `php phpunit --version` I get the expected result, that is `PHPUnit 5.0.8 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.`

I'm considering it a strange behaviour because I already installed PHPUnit in other machines and all worked fine.

So, someone knows why PHPUnit just works with a `php` before?

*Some important information*:

> Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
>
> PHP 5.6.14
>
> PHPUnit 5.0.8

`echo $PATH` returns `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin` that includes **/usr/local/bin**

`ls -l` in /usr/local/bin directory gives me `-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  2766207 Out 23 04:50 phpunit`

Comment: Right: "-rw-rw-r-- " phpunit has no "x" bit set. Therefore not executable.

Comment: Shame on me! Much more simple than I thought! A simple `chmod +x` solves the problem. Thx @ilkhd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by @ilkhd in the comments, the problem is inded with permission of the file.

Then, the solution is just:

```
$ cd /usr/local/bin
$ sudo chmod +x phpunit
```